# Textfield autocorrection issue

Tags: iphone

I am facing a strange and weird problem related with the UITextField's Autocorrection. 
I have a class which is derived from UIScrollView(subclass from UIScrollView), containing some textfield, textview & buttons at the bottom respectively.

I am facing a problem while i input some text in the textfield & autocorrection bubble pops up. If i tap on the bubble to resign it & tap on the button which presents the popover, it comes at correct dimensions. But if i don't disable the bubble and scroll up the view to tap the button, it pops up with wrong positions.

This is what i'm doing for presenting popover:

```
- (void)presentImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)type
             withAnimation:(BOOL)animated {
  if ([popoverViewController_ isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverViewController_ dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
  }

  UIImagePickerController *picker =
      [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
  [picker setDelegate:self];
  [picker setSourceType:type];
  [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor bloggerBarColor]];
  UIPopoverController *popoverController =
      [self popoverWithViewController:picker];
  CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

  if (type == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
    rect = [[composeView_ addPhotoLibraryButton] frame];
  } else {
    rect = [[composeView_ addPhotoCameraButton] frame];
  }

  [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                     inView:[self view]
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Tarun

Comment: what is your code for presenting the popup?

Comment: Pic of what is going on might be helpful also!

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith i have edited the post to show what i'm doing to present the popover.

Comment: Finally,I got the fix, I observed that the content offset was containing a -ve value for y-axis. So simply made a check to compare if it is less than zero and that's all.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I got the fix, I observed that the content offset was containing a -ve value for y-axis. So simply made a check to compare if it is less than zero and that's all.. :)